# When does a sequence not converge to a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When does a sequence not converge to a limit $L$?

I have a sequence converges to $L$ if and only if for all positive real numbers $e$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that the absolute value of the difference between any point of the sequence with an index greater than $N$ and $L$ is less than $e$.

It seems to me a sequence does not converge to $L$ if and only if for some positive real number $e$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that the absolute value of the difference between any point of the sequence with an index greater than $N$ and $L$ is greater than or equal to $e$.

But the reference I am relying on seems to imply a sequence does not converge to $L$ if and only if for some positive real number $e$ the absolute value of the difference between any point of the sequence and $L$ is greater than or equal to $e$.

Which is it?

With the latter I am having trouble seeing how the sequence $1, 2, 3, . . .$ does not converge to the real number $1$.

Comment: A sequence does not converge to $L$ if and only if there is some $e>0$ such that for all natural $N$ there is some natural $m>N$ such that $\lvert x_m-L\rvert\ge e$. Negating propositions is a computation, which you can work out outside-to-inside using $$\neg (\exists x\in A, P)\equiv \forall x\in A, \neg P\\ \neg (\forall x\in A, P)\equiv \exists x\in A, \neg P$$ stick to that and you'll never be wrong.

Comment: OK. I got it finally! Super. This works for me. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

It took a while, but I had to revisit the same question this time with the limit of a function.

It is helpful for me to think of these definitions as having three parts: a scope, a condition and an implication.

Let R be the set of real numbers and R+ be the positive cone of R.

Definition: The limit of a function f: A --> R at an accumulation point c of A is L if and only if

```
             for all e of R+ there exists d of R+ (THIS IS THE SCOPE)

             0 < | x - c | < d (THIS IS THE CONDITITION)

             implies | f(x) - L | < e (THIS IS THE IMPLICATION)
```

so, in this context, the limit of f at c is not L means we would . . .

reverse the SCOPE,

hold the CONDITION and

negate the IMPLICATION

Like this . . .

```
             for all d of R+ there exists e of R+ (SCOPE IS REVERSED)

             0 < | x - c | < d (CONDITITION IS HELD)

             implies e <= | f(x) - L | (IMPLICATION IS NEGATED)
```

Forgive me for not using the cool notation. Doesn't matter, no one will see this anyway.

I think my approach is sound and gets the point across better . . . for me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $a_n \to L$, expressed with quantifiers ($\forall$ meaning "for all" and $\exists$ meaning "there exists"), is

$$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n \ge N)( | a_n - L | < \varepsilon)$$

Consequently, if you want the opposite, you swap $\forall \leftrightarrow \exists$ and, in essence, take the negation (a logical "opposite" of sorts) of the final statement:

$$(\exists\varepsilon > 0)(\forall N \in \mathbb{N})(\exists n \ge N)( | a_n - L | \ge \varepsilon)$$

Hence, strictly as written, neither you nor the text is right on this matter.

Trying to express these statements solely in plain English is, frankly, quite cumbersome, and leads to these sorts of confusions.

Comment: I just found three on-line references that use "n greater than N" in the definition of a convergent sequence and not "n greater than or equal to N". I don't know how to use the cool notation on this site. Even so, I sometimes like to write things out completely in words to understand as it sometimes helps. Alas, I have never seen a book on analysis (or calculus for that matter) that relies solely on symbols for this definition. I do appreciate all the answers even though they seem to conflict a bit. I think the answer should work for both "greater than" and "greater than or equal to".

Comment: Yeah, $n \ge N$ and $n>N$ can be used interchangeably here, with suitable changes in $n$ and/or $N$. I'm simply accustomed to the $n \ge N$ convention due to my coursework. As far as the fancy writing goes, [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/13081) would be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

Where you say

> It seems to me ... for
> some positive real number  *there exists a natural number $N$*

you should say "... there is no natural number $N$".

Think about negating "every town has a mayor". You want "there is a town with no mayor" not "there is a town with a mayor".